# I there a R function for finding a minimum between to pairs?

Tags: r, optimization, convex

I need to identify pairs of variables that are dominated: if both values of the pair are lower than the other pairs in the data.

I already tried the functions `min` or `pmin` but I am not sure if they are the most appropriate.

```
   a = matrix(c(50,70), ncol = 2)
   b = matrix(c(45,85), ncol = 2)

  df = rbind(a,b)

Dominance <- function(a){
   for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
      for (j in 1:nrow(a)) {
         i1 <- rowSums(a[i,] < a[j,]) == ncol(a)
         a[i1,, drop = FALSE]
      }
   } 
   return(a) 
}
l = Dominance(df)

> l
  X1 X2
1 45 65
2 50 70
```

I expect the pair (45,65) to be removed.

Comment: Is it `45 65` or `45 85`.  Your input `b` is `45 85`

Comment: In case it is `45 65`the pair is removed. If it is `45 85` the pair stays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use do a comparison (`<`) between equal sized objects, then get the `rowSums`, if the sum is equal to the number of columns of the dataset, it implies all the elements in that row is less than the second data corresponding row

```
f1 <- function(mat1, mat2) {
            i1 <- !rowSums(mat1 < mat2) == ncol(mat1)
            i2 <- !rowSums(mat2 < mat1) == ncol(mat2)
           rbind(mat1, mat2)[c(i1, i2),, drop = FALSE]
   }

b <- matrix(c(45,65), ncol = 2)
b1 <- matrix(c(45,85), ncol = 2)



f1(a, b)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   50   70

f1(a, b1)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   50   70
#[2,]   45   85
```

Comment: Looks good. How to remove the dominated pair from the set then? i.e. when the result is TRUE?

Comment: I am checking right now! Not sure it works, seems it is not an index that is stored in `i1`, is that possible?

Comment: @Simon It is a logical vector and wrapping with `which(i1)` returns the row position.

Comment: I think OP needs - `rbind(
  a[rowSums(a < b) == ncol(a), , drop = F],
  b[rowSums(b < a) == ncol(b), , drop = F]
  )`

Comment: @Simon Do you need to check the reverse and do an `rbind` as Shree suggessted

Comment: @akrun, yes indeed I need to check the reverse. Updated my question with your suggestion. Are those 2 `for` loops ok to do what Shree suggests?

Comment: @akrun it works perfectly! Now do you know how to loop it for all rows in a data set?

Comment: @Simon It should work for all rows of the dataset assuming both are equal dimensions

Comment: @akrun what if I have a data set with 100 lines?

Comment: @Simon Doesn't matter as long as both datasets have same number of rows

Comment: @akrun and if I only have one data set and want to check all the lines pairwise?

Comment: @Simon Then you could do a `combn(seq_len(nrow(a)), 2, FUN = `

Comment: It says mat2 is missing